# quiero poder recoger el valor de varios botones dentro de un div

Tags: javascript

tengo este div con varios botones que forman un teclado, quiero poder recoger el valor de cada boton que corresponde a una letra. el codigo me da undefined y e probado otras cosas pero solo me dan el valor del primer boton.

```
<div id="teclado">
                <button  type="button" class="key" value="Q" style="border-style: 
                 outset;">Q</button>
                <button  type="button" class="key" value="W" style="border-style: 
                 outset;">W</button>
                <button  type="button" class="key" value="E" style="border-style: 
                 outset;">E</button>
                <button  type="button" class="key" value="R" style="border-style: 
                outset;">R</button>
                <button  type="button" class="key" value="T" style="border-style: 
                outset;">T</button>
                <button  type="button" class="key" value="Y" style="border-style: 
                outset;">Y</button>
                <button  type="button" class="key" value="U" style="border-style: 
                outset;">U</button>
                <button  type="button" class="key" value="I" style="border-style: 
                outset;">I</button>
                <button  type="button" class="key" value="O" style="border-style: 
                outset;">O</button>
                <button  type="button" class="key" value="P" style="border-style: 
                outset;">P</button>
                <br>





    document.querySelector('#teclado').addEventListener('click', () => 
        {
            const letra = document.querySelector('#teclado').value;
            alert(letra)
        
          
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

No es al `div` al que debes ponerle el evento `click`, es a cada uno de sus botones hijos.

Para ellos puedes seleccionar todos los botones dentro del `div` con la propiedad `children`, y agregarle el evento `click` a cada uno de ellos con la alerta correspondiente.

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
const botones = Array.from(document.getElementById('teclado').children);

botones.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
   alert(target.value)
   })})
```

```html
<div id="teclado">
    <button  type="button" class="key" value="Q" style="border-style: 
     outset;">Q</button>
    <button  type="button" class="key" value="W" style="border-style: 
     outset;">W</button>
    <button  type="button" class="key" value="E" style="border-style: 
     outset;">E</button>
    <button  type="button" class="key" value="R" style="border-style: 
    outset;">R</button>
    <button  type="button" class="key" value="T" style="border-style: 
    outset;">T</button>
    <button  type="button" class="key" value="Y" style="border-style: 
    outset;">Y</button>
    <button  type="button" class="key" value="U" style="border-style: 
    outset;">U</button>
    <button  type="button" class="key" value="I" style="border-style: 
    outset;">I</button>
    <button  type="button" class="key" value="O" style="border-style: 
    outset;">O</button>
    <button  type="button" class="key" value="P" style="border-style: 
    outset;">P</button>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Entendiendo lo que requieres, te comparto el código con las respectivas correcciones.

1. Al evento click le agregamos 1 parámetro, este, nos permite capturar a que elemento se le dió click que se encuentra dentro del div con id teclado.
2. Obtenemos el valor del elemento capturado, es decir desde el elemento que se dió el click, en este caso cualquiera de los botones.
3. Creamos un if, para filtrar que dicho valor no sea undefined, esto debido a que el que lanza el evento no es directamente el botón sino el que contiene los botones, entonces si se da click fuera de los botones pero dentro del elemento padre, es decir el `<div id="teclado">` va a crearse la variable letra con valor undefined.
4. Almacenamos en la variable global que creamos los valores de los botones que se presionaron.
5. Mostramos en pantalla, la información de la variable global `texto` a través de un nuevo div que creamos para el ejemplo `<div id="result"></div>`

```js
let texto = '';
document.querySelector('#teclado').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const letra = e.target.value;
  if (e.target.value !== undefined) {
    texto += letra;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = texto;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="teclado">
  <button type="button" class="key" value="Q" style="border-style: 
                 outset;">Q</button>
  <button type="button" class="key" value="W" style="border-style: 
                 outset;">W</button>
  <button type="button" class="key" value="E" style="border-style: 
                 outset;">E</button>
  <button type="button" class="key" value="R" style="border-style: 
                outset;">R</button>
  <button type="button" class="key" value="T" style="border-style: 
                outset;">T</button>
  <button type="button" class="key" value="Y" style="border-style: 
                outset;">Y</button>
  <button type="button" class="key" value="U" style="border-style: 
                outset;">U</button>
  <button type="button" class="key" value="I" style="border-style: 
                outset;">I</button>
  <button type="button" class="key" value="O" style="border-style: 
                outset;">O</button>
  <button type="button" class="key" value="P" style="border-style: 
                outset;">P</button>
  <br>
</div>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.

Comment: si, me fue muy bien, gracias